# Groovy pass shell commands to function

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

A function that triggers passed shell commands using withCredentials in Jenkins. For example instead of doing this

```
 withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'amazon',
                        usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
            //Shell commands block
            sh """
            echo 'hello world'
            echo 'Good bye'
            """
        }
```

Trigger it like that

```
def performWithCredentials(command_block){
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'amazon',
                        usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
            //Passed command_block
        }
}
```

What will be the propper way to call it inside a job step in Jenkins?

Thanks and cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the block to `withCredentials`;

```
def performWithCredentials(command_block){
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                       credentialsId: 'amazon',
                       usernameVariable: 'USERNAME',
                       passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']], command_block)
}
```

Comment: can you see the update and suggest a caller actually for that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own delegates in [groovy/pipelines](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/04/21/dsl-plugins/)

You can turn it into

```
performWithCredentials(delegate) {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
        credentialsId: 'amazon',
        usernameVariable: 'USERNAME',
        passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
        delegate()
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
performWithCredentials {
    ...
    <your code here>
    ...
}
```

You can even make a file `performWithCredentials.groovy` with a function `call(..)` (see [tutorial](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/04/21/dsl-plugins/)) and store that in `$JENKINS_HOME/workflow-libs/`. 
Restart Jenkins and have it globally available